# Hibernate returns an array returns duplicated columns

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I execute the following query with Hibernate, and the object array returned has identical values in positions 2 and 3, when in the DB these values are different. The database is Oracle and Hibernate is version 3.2.6. This happens only in production and a specific customer (using WebSphere), in dev and other customers works fine.

```
String sql = " SELECT acc.account_code," +
             "        acct.description, " +
             "       ( SELECT SUM(item_amount)" +
             "         FROM gem_book_entry_item bi, gem_document d" +
             "         WHERE account_id = acc.dboid AND " +
             "               account_sign = 1 AND " +
             "               bi.document_id = d.dboid AND " +
             "               d.state_id = :definitive AND " +
             "               (d.internal_reference IS NULL OR d.internal_reference NOT IN (:references)) AND " +
             "               d.posting_approval_date <= :refDate" +
             "       ) ," +
             "       ( SELECT SUM(item_amount)" +
             "         FROM gem_book_entry_item bi, gem_document d" +
             "         WHERE account_id = acc.dboid AND " +
             "               account_sign = -1 AND " +
             "               bi.document_id = d.dboid AND " +
             "               d.state_id = :definitive AND " +
             "               (d.internal_reference IS NULL OR d.internal_reference NOT IN (:references)) AND " +
             "               d.posting_approval_date <= :refDate" +
             "        ) ," +
             "        acc.init_balance" +
             " FROM gem_account acc, gem_account_t acct " +
             " WHERE acc.dboid = acct.dboid AND " +
             "       acc.institution_id = :institutionId AND " +
             "       acc.period_code = :periodCode AND " +
             "       acct.lang = :langId " ;
```

Comment: Did you run the query on PROD manually?

Comment: Yes I did and it worked, but using a C++ client that uses Oracle client. I guess it's a bug of the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Hibernate bug:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4956

Using aliases is the workaround.